# Sync Framework With Microsoft CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-sync-framework

Can anyone provide any guidance on how I would begin to use the sync framework to sync a Microsoft CRM environment with a custom database?

I assume I would have to write a custom provider for the CRM side? 
Are there any examples out there of this? (csutom provider using web service or CRM)

Answer (score 0):

if you sync directly using the CRM tables, the out of the box sync providers should work.
however, MS CRM tables are not that friendly when accessed directly and the recommended way is to go via the API. in that case, you will have to write your own custom sync provider.